# Should I COMMIT after creating a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, commit, stored-functions

If I create a function, is it best practice to `COMMIT` after its creation?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction (somevar varchar2)
   ...
   END
```

It executes and adds the function to the database, but should I add a `COMMIT` to the bottom of the file? Perhaps also wrap with `BEGIN` and `END`?

Comment: Every time you issue a CREATE..DROP..TRUNCATE - you are also implicitly doing a COMMIT. Adding another COMMIT won't hurt anything, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a function is a DDL operation. You don't need to commit after creating it.

As committing there is just pointless, the best practice would be not **not** commit after creating a function.